# Selected Data only post within the same page PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have paging data table with checkbox on it,when i selected the checkbox,it only post the selected checkbox in the same page,here is my view :

```
<label>Category</label>
<select name="cat" id="cat>
   <option value="Motorcycle">Motorcycles</option>
   <option value="Motorcycle">Cars</option>
</select>


<table id="tabelgg" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>NO.</th>
                  <th>NAME</th>
                  <th>ACTION</th>

              </tr>
        </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        <?php
                           $no=1;
                           foreach ($cats as $data) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$no."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$data['name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td><center><input type='checkbox' name='desc[]' id='desc[]' value='".$data['id_list']."'></center></td></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $no++;
                           }
                        ?>
                  </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is my save controller

```
  if(isset($_POST['desc']))
           {
             if (is_array($_POST['desc'])) 
                {
                     foreach($_POST['desc'] as $check){

        $data_=array('cat' => $this->input->post('cat'),
                     'item_head' => $check);
                }                                   
                 } else {
               $value = $_POST['ket'];
               echo $value;
                }

           $this->db->insert('tbl_pengelompokan',$data_);
           }

                redirect('admin/pengelompokan','location');
```

how do i make change for my controller view so it will post one-to-many data ?

Comment: You should ask a question here.

Comment: forgot to ask it @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable javascript plugin to do that. I use server side script to show many data as well on one request as dynamic.